# Combine code and print result to excel .csv file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I have 2 script files in python

1, This one keeps only numbers and remove characters that are not.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from re import sub


data = pd.read_csv("C:/Path_to_csv_file.csv")
data.columns=["var1", "var2", "var3"]


var1_list = list(data.var1)
var2_list = list(data.var2)
var3_list = list(data.var3)


print("var1")    
for i in (data.var1):
    a=re.sub("[^\d\.]", "", i)
    float(a) 
    print(a) 
print("\n\n")

print("date")    
for i in (data.date):
    a=re.sub("[^\d\.]", "", i)
    float(a) 
    print(a) 
print("\n\n")

print("var3")    
for i in (data.var3):
    a=re.sub("[^\d\.]", "", i)
    float(a) 
    print(a) 
print("\n\n")
```

2, This one keeps 2 digits before the period (from left)

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from re import sub


data = pd.read_csv("C:/Path_to_csv_file.csv")
data.columns=["var1", "var2", "var3"]


var1_list = list(data.var1)
var2_list = list(data.var2)
var3_list = list(data.var3)


print("var1")
for i in (var1_list):
    formatted = format(i, '02.0f')
    print(formatted[-2:])
print("\n\n")

print("var2")
for i in (var2_list):
    formatted = format(i, '02.0f')
    print(formatted[-2:])
print("\n\n")

print("var3")
for i in (var3_list):
    formatted = format(i, '02.0f')
    print(formatted[-2:])
print("\n\n")
```

How to combine them and get the final result print directly in a excel csv file (to the pandas data file or a new file, both ways are fine).

When I combined it I got trouble with the data type. Before the script 1 every result is understood as `string`. The result looks like this `w[var1] = -1282.982`

Answer (score 1):

Hi I suggest that you make your .csv file to a pandas dataframe and then use the method pd.concat(....). Hope this helps!